# Simple proxy requiring another proxy with twisted

Tags: python, proxy, twisted

I came across this simple proxy example that uses Twisted:

```
# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import proxy, server

site = server.Site(proxy.ReverseProxyResource('yahoo.com', 80, ''))
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
reactor.run()
```

The issue is that my computer needs to use a proxy itself to access the web, so I was wondering if there is a way to specify those proxy settings?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. At least, there's not an easy way to do it with Twisted.

`ReverseProxyResource` delegates to `ReverseProxyRequest` which does a [direct TCP connection](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/web/proxy.py#L214) to the specified host (in this case, yahoo.com).

You could *probably* cobble something together by adapting `ReverseProxyRequest` to use `twisted.web.client.ProxyAgent`.  Arguably, Twisted itself should provide a way to parametrize `ReverseProxyResource` by agent.