# Twisted - forwarding proxy requests to another proxy (proxy chain)

Tags: python, twisted, http-proxy

I am setting up a HTTP proxy in python to filter web content. I found a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9469400/1061891) on StackOverflow which does exactly this using [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/). However, I need another proxy to access the web. So, the proxy needs to forward requests to another proxy. What is the best way to do this using [twisted.web.proxy](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.web.proxy.html)?

I found [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227937/simple-proxy-requiring-another-proxy-with-twisted) which needs something similar, but from a *reverse proxy*.

My best guess is that it should be possible to build a chained proxy by modifying or subclassing `twisted.web.proxy.ProxyClient` to connect to the next proxy instead of connecting to the web directly. Unfortunately I didn't find any clues in the documentation on how to do this.

The code I have so far ([cite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9469400/1061891)):

```
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.web import http, proxy

class ProxyClient(proxy.ProxyClient):
    def handleResponsePart(self, buffer):
        proxy.ProxyClient.handleResponsePart(self, buffer)

class ProxyClientFactory(proxy.ProxyClientFactory):
    protocol = ProxyClient

class ProxyRequest(proxy.ProxyRequest):
    protocols = dict(http=ProxyClientFactory)

class Proxy(proxy.Proxy):
    requestFactory = ProxyRequest

class ProxyFactory(http.HTTPFactory):
    protocol = Proxy

portstr = "tcp:8080:interface=localhost"  # serve on localhost:8080

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from twisted.internet import endpoints, reactor

    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    endpoint = endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, portstr)
    d = endpoint.listen(ProxyFactory())
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not hard to implement using Twisted. Let me give you a simple example.

Suppose the first proxy is `proxy1.py`, like the code you pasted in your question;
the second proxy is `proxy2.py`.

For `proxy1.py`, you just need to override the `process` function of class `ProxyRequest`. Like this:

```
class ProxyRequest(proxy.ProxyRequest):
    def process(self):
        parsed = urllib_parse.urlparse(self.uri)
        protocol = parsed[0]
        host = parsed[1].decode('ascii')
        port = self.ports[protocol]
        if ':' in host:
            host, port = host.split(':')
            port = int(port)
        rest = urllib_parse.urlunparse((b'', b'') + parsed[2:])
        if not rest:
            rest = rest + b'/'
        class_ = self.protocols[protocol]
        headers = self.getAllHeaders().copy()
        if b'host' not in headers:
            headers[b'host'] = host.encode('ascii')
        self.content.seek(0, 0)
        s = self.content.read()
        clientFactory = class_(self.method, rest, self.clientproto, headers, s, self)
        if (NeedGoToSecondProxy):
            self.reactor.connectTCP(your_second_proxy_server_ip, your_second_proxy_port, clientFactory)
        else:
            self.reactor.connectTCP(host, port, clientFactory)
```

For `proxy2.py`, you just need to set up another simple proxy. A problem need to be noticed though, you may need to override `process` function in `proxy2.py` again, because the `self.uri` may not be valid after the proxy forward (chain).

For example, the original `self.uri` should be `http://www.google.com/something?para1=xxx`, and you may find it as `/something?para1=xxx` only, at second proxy. So you need to extract the host info from `self.headers` and complement the `self.uri` so that your second proxy can normally deliver it to the correct destination.